# How to do periodic job in Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to do periodic job (cron-job) every ten minutes, which loads data from `Postgresql`. `GenerateSequence` is used to implement it, here are the codes.

```java
    PostgresOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(PostgresOptions.class);

    // create pipeline
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    PGSimpleDataSource pgDataSource = getPostgresDataSource(options);

    // run sequence
    PCollection<KV<String, Float>> sequence = pipeline.apply(
            "Generate Sequence",
            GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardMinutes(10))
    ).apply(
        "Read Postgresql",
            ParDo.of(new ReadPG(pgDataSource))
    );

...

    private static class ReadPG extends DoFn<Long, KV<String, Float>> {
        private PGSimpleDataSource pgDataSource;
        public ReadPG(PGSimpleDataSource source) {
            pgDataSource = source;
        }

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement( @Element Long seq, final OutputReceiver<KV<String, Float>> receiver) {
            JdbcIO.<KV<String, Float>>read()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(this.pgDataSource))
                .withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), SerializableCoder.of(Float.class)))
                .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<String, Float>>() {
                    public KV<String, Float> mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                        KV<String, Float> kv = KV.of(resultSet.getString("id"), resultSet.getFloat("key1"));
                        while (resultSet.next()) {
                            System.out.println(resultSet.getString("id"));
                        }
                        receiver.output(kv);

                        return kv;
                    }
                })
                .withQuery("select * from table_name limit 10;");
        }
    }
```

However, there is no data is loaded from `Postgresql`. Is there anything wrong in my codes?

Beam version: 2.15.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Beam PTransform has to be part of pipeline and you can't use it just inside `processElement()` since it won't be translated by runner as part of DAG. If you are looking for [composite transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#composite-transforms) then it could be achieved by overriding `expand()` method of other PTransform.

In the same time, Beam is not intended to schedule jobs to run on your backend processing engine, so it should be do performed out of Beam. Some options are mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#is_there_a_built-in_scheduling_mechanism_to_execute_pipelines_at_given_time_or_interval).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the periodic job is made it through `GenerateSequence` and `Window`.

Here are sample codes

```java
        pipeline.apply(
                "Generate Sequence",
                GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardMinutes(WindowInterval))
        )
        .apply(Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(WindowInterval))))
        .apply("Read Data from PG", new ReadPG(pgDataSource))
```